# Magento 2 - Html Tags in Comment Section of Transactional E-Mails

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, transactional-mail

I'm struggling around trying allowing html tags in order/invoice comments which are sending out to customer via transaction emails.

What i did:

```
{{var comment |raw}}
```

Edited the comment variable, removing the |escape|nl2br tags and adding the |raw tag. In my understanding the raw tag is for allowing html without beeing striped out, but it's not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

By default Magento does not allow html tags in the order comments.
It's in the controller that handles the comments.

Take a look in `vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/AddComment.php`. There is a line which trims html tags.

```
$comment = trim(strip_tags($data['comment']));
```

So if you want tags in comments you need to rewrite the method `execute`.
Follow the steps mentioned [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/) to override the controller in your custom module.

You will have to override the phtml file as well if you wish to display comments on frontend.

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/comments.phtml
```

and change this line:

```
<dd class="comment text"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_commentItem->getComment()) ?></dd>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: hey @sejal. thx for your feedback, it heped me a bit out. now the frontend is rendering fine in customer account. the comments are added incl. html to the database though the strip_tags. i still face the issue that the comment in the transactional mail has no html tags. i think i have to check the output of the variable comment but i cannot find the code