# Magento 2 How to send HTML in Order Comment Section of Transactional E-Mails

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-email

I am trying to send HTML structure in order comment section, but in email it convert in simple plain text.

Comment:

> `Hello, <a href="example.com">Click Here</a>`

Current Output:

> `Hello, Click Here`

Expected Output:

> Hello, [Click Here](http://example.com/)

I have tried with this code but its not working: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/186477/62614

Comment: Are you sure you have selected the email `Template Type : HTML` not `Text`.

Comment: @AmitNaraniwal in order comment section i couldn't find template type.